# Interpreting to system keypresses on Android

Tags: android, mono, keyboard, text-editor, key-events

I have a custom view.  I am displaying the system keyboard from my view.  I have set my keypressHandler, so I am getting callbacks to the following method.

```
public bool OnKey(View v, Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
```

[This is all via Mono, so for Java guys reading this, the method names may differ slightly].

My problem is that it is far from obvious to me how to turn this information into an understanding of what the user is trying to do.  I am logging some of the information from the keyCode and keyEvent; I've reproduced it below.  But I don't understand how to get information like "The user is trying to insert the letter 'q'", or "The user wants to delete a character.", and so forth.  I could write my own custom framework for it, but that has got to be a bad idea -- is there a way to get that information from the system?

My code and some of the debugger output:

```
public bool OnKey(View v, Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e) {
  KeyEventActions action = e.Action;
  string actionString = action.ToString ();
  string text = keyCode.ToString ();
  KeyCharacterMap map = e.KeyCharacterMap;
  MetaKeyStates meta = e.MetaState;
  char label = map.GetDisplayLabel (keyCode);
  CommonDebug.LogLine (actionString, "action detected", "code=", text, "meta=", meta.ToString (), "label=", label.ToString ());   // custom console writing method.
}

[AAA] Down action detected code= H meta= 0 label= H
[AAA] Up action detected code= H meta= 0 label= H
[AAA] Down action detected code= ShiftLeft meta= 65 label= ��
[AAA] Down action detected code= H meta= 65 label= H
[AAA] Up action detected code= H meta= 65 label= H
[AAA] Up action detected code= ShiftLeft meta= 0 label= ��
[AAA] Down action detected code= ShiftLeft meta= 65 label= ��
[AAA] Down action detected code= D meta= 65 label= D
[AAA] Up action detected code= D meta= 65 label= D
```

For what it's worth, in iOS I would be working with the following method:

```
 textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:
```

Comment: I would recommend looking at how `TextView` and `EditText` deal with it.

Comment: I agree, I don't really want KeyUp and KeyDown; that's just what I was finding.  What I really want is what characters are being inserted.  It would be a big step to find a way to get that information.

Comment: Use TextWatcher. This will tell you when a character is going to be inserted or deleted. You need EditText view to which the key presses are related. Another (rather awkward) way: use logic in your code, like pressing KEY_CODE_DEL - user wants to delete, pressing KEY_CODE_INSERT user is inserting/replacing.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Gabe Sechan's comment, here is a partial answer.  It does get the inserted text.  That's a big step.  However, so far, I can't figure out how to detect delete or enter keypresses this way.

Like the question, the answer is via Mono.  Java folks will have slightly different method names, but the basic technique should work just fine.

My InputConnection class:

```
  public class TextInputConnection: BaseInputConnection {
    public TextInputConnection(IntPtr javaReference, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership transfer): base(javaReference, transfer) {
    }
    public TextInputConnection(View view, bool fullEditor): base(view, fullEditor) {
    }
    public override bool CommitText(Java.Lang.ICharSequence text, int newCursorPosition) {
      bool r = base.CommitText (text, newCursorPosition);
      CommonDebug.LogLine ("Committing text", text.ToString(), newCursorPosition.ToString (), "returning", r.ToString()); // this is my console logging method, which logs to channel AAA.  You'll want to substitute yours, or do whatever it is you want to do with the text.
      return r;
    }
    public override bool PerformEditorAction(ImeAction actionCode) {
      CommonDebug.LogLine ("PerformEditorAction", actionCode.ToString ());
      return false;
    }
  }
```

In my View subclass:

```
  public override IInputConnection OnCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
    TextInputConnection r = new TextInputConnection (this, true);
    return r;
  }
```

When I type "Dog" on the keyboard, I see the following in the console:

```
[AAA] Committing text D 1 returning True
[AAA] Committing text o 1 returning True
[AAA] Committing text g 1 returning True
```

This is considerable progress as I am getting the actual inserted characters.  An "enter" keypress does fire the PerformEditorAction method, but the ActionCode is "ImeNull", so it doesn't seem very helpful.  And a delete keypress doesn't trigger anything that I can see.